# why playbook is doesn't play?

Tags: ansible

I have a problem, I try start my playbook and I get an error:

> ERROR! 'task' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to have been in '/root/devops/ansible/playbook2.yml': line 2, column 4, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
 - name: nginx
   ^ here
```

my playbook:

```
 - name: nginx
   hosts: all
   become: yes

   task:
   - name: install
     apt:  name=nginx state=latest

   - name: start nginx
     service: name=nginx.service state=started enabled=yes
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `tasks`.

```
 - name: nginx
   hosts: all
   become: yes

   tasks:
   - name: install
     apt:  name=nginx state=latest

   - name: start nginx
     service: name=nginx.service state=started enabled=yes
```

Refer [playbook-language-example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-language-example) for ansible playbook syntax.